# CIrcular Inclusion

Tags: c++, class, include

I am building a Tetris, and trying to avoid pointers. In the code below I am trying to define an instance of a class **"ButtonQuit"** in another class **"TetrisWindow"**, both classes use each others' methods. I keep getting an error:

```
‘ButtonQuit’ does not name a type: ButtonQuit btnQuit;
```

or:

```
field ‘btnQuit’ has incomplete type: ButtonQuit btnQuit;
```

I understand that there is a circular inclusion, but I can't figure out how to solve this. I've tried forward declaring **ButtonQuit**, it doesn't work.

(**WindowSDL** is just a class that holds all the graphics functions, it has no includes in it, apart from SDL.)

Here is my code(When I compile this i get "does not name a type" error):

**BUTTONQUIT.HPP:**

```
#ifndef __BUTTONQUIT__
#define __BUTTONQUIT__

#include <TetrisWindow.hpp>

class ButtonQuit{

private:

int x,y;
TetrisWindow win;

public:

ButtonQuit (TetrisWindow, int, int);
~ButtonQuit();
void print(void);
void action(void);
bool clicked(int, int);


};

#endif
```

**TETRISWINDOW.HPP:**

```
#ifndef __TETRISWINDOW__
#define __TETRISWINDOW__

#include <cstdint>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

#include <WindowSDL.hpp>
#include <ButtonQuit.hpp>

class TetrisWindow: public WindowSDL{

protected:

ButtonQuit btnQuit;
void handleEvent(SDL_Event&);
void work(void);

public:

TetrisWindow();
TetrisWindow(uint16_t, uint16_t);
TetrisWindow(const TetrisWindow& w);
~TetrisWindow();

void drawWindow(void);

};

#endif
```

Comment: Make one ot the other a pointer. Then use forward declaration

Comment: You will notice that the two classes both contain instances of the other class.  That means that each class must fully know the size/definition of each other.  If the size of one changes, then the size of the other needs to change, but then the first one needs to change ITs size, and then...  You get the picture.  This is why pointers (and/or references) is the best answer when you have circular "containment" dependency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your class `TetrisWindow` consists of a `ButtonQuit` (and a few member functions). This `ButtonQuit` again has a member of type `TetrisWindow` (which has a member of type `ButtonQuit` which has a member of type `TetrisWindow` which....).

With this sheme you won't solve your problem, both beeing a member of each other is simply impossible.

What you need is some kind of "knows about" rather than a "consists of" relations.

Usually this is done with pointers, so it would probably make sense to let your `ButtonQuit` have a member `TetrisWindow* parent` - this is a non-owning pointer and your can declare your `TetrisWindow` e.g. as a global variable with automatic storage duration (which means no need to `delete` it).

Another option for a "knows about" relationship would be references, but a reference needs to be set in the constructor - which would mean you need to construct `TetrisWindow` before `ButtonQuit` and `ButtonQuit` before `TetrisWindow`.

Comment: Thank you very much, now I understand where the problem is coming from. Thank you very much for your time.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is not the circular inclusion in your situation, that's a secondary issue.

The first issue you should think about is that `TetrisWindow` has a `ButtonQuit` member and `ButtonQuit` has a `TetrisWindow` member.

These two members are not pointers nor references, which means that they will be stored in their entire size inside the containing class. This leads to a recursive structure which doesn't end.

A `TetrisWindow` must contain a `ButtonQuit` which must contain a `TetrisWindow` which must contain a `ButtonQuit`...

The solution here is to forward declare both classes in respective other headers and use pointers/references instead, eg:

```
// TetrisWindow.h
class ButtonQuit;

class TetrisWindow {
  private:
    ButtonQuit* button;
  ...
}

// ButtonQuit.h
class TetrisWindow;

class ButtonQuit {
  private:
    TetrisWindow* window;
  ...
}
```

Now you are using pointers as members so the compiler doesn't have to know `sizeof(ButtonQuit)` or `sizeof(TetrisWindow)` for the definitions, since a pointer is always a pointer. This allows you to not include the headers of the other class at all, as long as you don't have inline functions which try to access the incomplete type.

Comment: It's likely that `TetrisWindow::button` shouldn't be a pointer.

Comment: @BarryTheHatchet: Or it should be an `unique_ptr<ButtonQuit>`, with the destructor of `TetrisWindow` not defined inline to avoid inclusion of the header. It actually depends on the design you are trying to achieve and how much coupling betwen header inclusions you want.

Comment: @BarryTheHatchet Thank you very much I got the idea. Thank you again!

Comment: Could you elaborate how compiler know the `sizeof()`?

Comment: @NERDYLIZARD: If you are storing a pointer to `ButtonQuit` inside `TetrisWindow` then the compiler doesn't need to know `sizeof(ButtonQuit)` to compute the layout of TetrisWindow since `sizeof(ButtonQuit*)` is enough. And `sizeof(ButtonQuit*) == sizeof(void*)` so there is no need to know anything about `ButtonQut`

Comment: so, when does compiler acknowledge the size of `ButtonQuit`?

Comment: @NERDYLIZARD  wherever it is required but not for definition of TetrisWindow

Comment: One last, how is it equal to `sizeof(*void)`? and what is the `sizeof(void*)`